# \ddot over greek letters

Tags: math-mode

I have following usage requirement for `\ddot`. However, the output is not pleasing.

```
\ddot{\delta_0}   \ddot{w_0}
```

The double dots are getting centered about `\delta_0`  and `w_0`.  However, I feel it should have been good if the double dots centered about `\delta` and `w`.

Your inputs are appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `\ddot\delta_0` and `\ddot w_0` ?

Comment: The doubly dotted letter is `\delta` or `w`; so the subscript is to the doubly dotted letter: hence `\ddot{\delta}_{0}`. The braces are not really necessary, but they are good practice.

Answer (score 1):

What's about:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\ddot{\delta_g}$
$\ddot{\delta}_g$
\end{document}
```